# AVPlayer Audio can not mute - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am trying to mute video sound while playing.

I am using below code for playing mp4 file.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Spalsh", ofType: "mp4")

 let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
 let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
 playerLayer.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
 playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
 player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
 player.isMuted = true
 player.play()


player.isMuted  is not working
```

Comment: Not related to the question but Why don't you just use the url Bundle's method `Bundle.main.url(forResource: , withExtension:)` to get your url?

Comment: Can you add some more code/context to your question? Show your video controller and where/how you are calling it and the most important where are you declaring your AVPlayer.